# Magento2 admin panel arning: file_put_contents(): Only 0 of 68 bytes written, possibly out of free disk space

Tags: admin, magento2

i m setting up new magento2 installation and try to access admin panel but we got below error how to solve!

i m try to change permission 664 file and 775 for var directory

Warning: file_put_contents(): Only 0 of 68 bytes written, possibly out of free disk space in /home/etoolsmart/public_html/magentonew/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php on line 693

Warning: file_put_contents(): Only 0 of 68 bytes written, possibly out of free disk space in /home/etoolsmart/public_html/magentonew/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php on line 693

Comment: how about possibly out of free disk space? Are u using file cache?

Comment: yes we are using page cache